# Required attribute in Dynamo.DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm using Dynamo.DB and following "https://www.npmjs.org/package/dynamodb" for Node.JS; I was wondering how I can have an attribute as "required"?

Here there is an example I found in the documentation, but I'm not sure if we can have "required" attribute in Dynamo.DB or not?

```
// flat [string, number, string array or number array] based json object
var item = { score: 304,
             date: (new Date).getTime(),
             sha: '3d2d6963',
             usr: 'spolu',
             lng: ['node', 'c++'] };

ddb.putItem('a-table', item, {}, function(err, res, cap) {});
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can. Only the primary key is required, since DynamoDB is 'schema-less', it doesn't really make sense to have a required attribute on a field in a schema-less database.

Comment: Correct - there is no way in DynamoDB (a schema-less database) to mark attributes as required (other than the primary key).  The one exception to this is that if you put items in a table with secondary indexes if you include the index keys (they are optional), they must have the same type as the types you defined in the index schema in the CreateTable call.

Comment: since DynamoDB is 'schema-less', i'm wondering are there any benefits of using `AttributeDefinitions` for field which is not partition(primary) key? No matter if field is defined or not in `AttributeDefinitions` using `{ AttributeName: "...", AttributeType: "..." }` DynamoDB will save it.

Comment: @Srle I'm still learning DDB, but it looks like the sort key and projected attributes for any local secondary indexes you create must be defined on the table. They don't have to have values for every item, however, as sparse indexes are allowed.